# Custom side bar menu to show children of current page

Tags: wordpress, menu, sidebar

I am just getting my head around wordpress and I need to create a sidebar menu.

What I need to do is display the custom menu but if I'm on a parent page which has children, display all top level pages and in a submenu, display the child pages of the parent.

I know I can display all the pages in the menu like this

```
<?php wp_list_pages('depth=2&title_li=' ); ?>
```

But I want to hide all child pages from the menu that are not children of the current page

What I have so far is some code which does the child pages bit but it doesn't display the top level pages. All top level pages should be displayed at all time.

```
<?php
if($post->post_parent){
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&include=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); 
    $children .= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
} else {
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
}
if ($children) { ?>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

How can I combine the 2 examples so all top level pages are visible and only children of the current page are visible at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using css

```
.page_item_has_children ul.children{display:none}
li.current_page_item ul.children{display:block}
```